# How to create a class/component diagram out of my React Project?

Tags: reactjs, components, uml

I would like to visualise the components I have used in my project. I have used PHP for the backend and Laravel+Reactjs for the frontend.

What I want to achieve is to understand all the components that depend on each other and how/what they pass to each other.

Is there a way to automatically generate the class/component diagram out of the project in phpstorm or vscode? Can I visualise it on the Chrome's dev tool? Note: I am already using the Chrome dev tool for react component.

Comment: There's no tools I know of that do it based on your source code, though there are ones that will do it based on a live app (as in show the components and their hierarchy in real time). Might be your best option

Comment: @Jayce444, Can you name some of these tools?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [dependency-cruiser](https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser).

`dependency-cruiser` can visualise dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I found React Architect (https://www.reactarchitect.ai) to create component diagrams, they have a free version, too

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Google extension called [Realize for React](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/realize-for-react/llondniabnmnappjekpflmgcikaiilmh) for my project, which in the developer tool helps visualize components that appear on a specific route.

But the extension crashes often.